# Why Angular build didn't package the app folder?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I just create the default app and I run it with nodejs server on `http://localhost:4200/` and everything works fine. But, I try to build this app and deploy it to the HTTPD server. I use `ng build --prod` and I get `dist` folder but there is no `app` folder in this folder and there is no `app.component.html`. Ok, maybe Angular render this from some js file but when I try to load `index.html` from my HTTPD server I get a blank page.

Comment: Dist folder is contains everything you need. Unpack dist folder to the root and get index.html like http://example.org/index.html

Comment: But I did that. My other application works but this one just render a blank page.

Comment: Ok. 1.  Did you see index.html inside the dist folder? 2. Check console in browsers for the errors. What are the results?

Comment: Hm.. there is some error `Loading module from “http://localhost:8080/runtime-es2015.c9afb3256f2870e161de.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).my-app` Maybe some server configuration with loading js and css. I will check because temporary I don't have any other page with js and css

Comment: But, I see that it try to fetch from root and not from app folder

Comment: Yes, I needed to put `ng build --prod --base-href=/my-app/` Tnx

Answer (score 1):

I needed to put command to indicate base folder for load js and css files. Like this `ng build --prod --base-href=/my-app/`

Comment: Unpack dist folder to the root - was the first suggestion :) Glad to see that problem already fixed

Comment: Yes, I realized that you told me. Tnx and sorry. I should check logs before.